# Which Android device to get for app testing?

Tags: android

I am beginning Android app development and I would like to know which device would give me the most comprehensive testing environment. I would like my app to be compatible with the most number of devices without breaking the bank by buying a dozen devices. Just testing on the emulator is not an option because it runs at 1/10th of normal speed.

**OS Version**

Should I purchase a device with the most common OS? As of now, 2.2 is the most popular. Obviously, a 2.2 device wouldn't be able to test run an app made for 3.0. But is the reverse also true? If I buy a 3.0 device, would that allow me to test all lower versions?

[image: android os version market share]

**Tablet or Phone**

Given that my app won't be dealing with phone calls, should I be buying a phone or tablet? Are the two sufficiently the same except for resolution? Has your app ever worked on a tablet but failed on a phone? The Apple iPad has a neat emulation mode for iPhone apps. Is this feature also available on Android tablets?

Price is also a big consideration when choosing a tablet over a phone. I'm not going to sign up for another cellular plan, so most phones would have me fork over $500+. That would come out to be the same price as the Motorola Xoom. But arguably Android phones are much more popular than tablets, so a Xoom wouldn't let me see what most of my users would be seeing.

Comment: I recommend the Nexus S from Google.  It's a true developer phone and will be updated for longer than most phones.

Comment: Android is backwards compatible meaning newer versions support all older versions. They may look funny but they'll run for the most part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating applications which requires a lot of custom drawing/animating such a game, then a slew of devices would be ideal to test against resolutions, DPI, RAM, CPU power, etc.

If you are using more of the native components then you do not have to worry as much about the different screen types and sizes as these tend to scale very well.

This question was brought up at GDC's Android Developer Day, you may be able to find the video online. Basically, it boiled down to trying to get one of each kind of device, low end, mid, high. It was also recommended that you built for the newest SDK, then start building against older ones, fixing, testing, rebuilding.

Therefore, I would personally recommend the Nexus S.

The company I work for does Android development on the original G1, HTC Hero, Samsung Epic 4G, and HTC Incredible.

Answer (score 2):

In general it's up to you, I suggest you Google Nexus S, because of NFC module in that phone (only that phone nowadays as I good know have NFC), besides that it has everything you need. Big plus for screen.

Android 3.0 is made generally for tablets but of course you can write application in 3.0 and run it on 2.2 or 2.3 just look for backward compatibility, and use reflection.

Also good to know that it does not depend of your phone which version you have it's up to SDK ver which you choose during creating project, in general you can set 7 as min SDK and test it on phone with 9.

Comment: How does the NFC help with app development?

Comment: It does not help but it's good to have it, by newest research in 2014 (as far as I remember) each 5th smartphone will have it, so maybe in close future you will have to write something with NFC and it's really hard to test it on emulator.